# using virtualbox to facilitate installation and backup

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

We have recently created a product that need a very long and hard configuration when it's deployed .So i'm thinking of creating a virtual machine with virtualbox that contains the product configured and install it in production .
Is this a good idea ?
Is virtualbox stable enough to support this kind of use ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use VirtualBox for the same purposes, it is very stable. Just don't think that such test is enough for your product. You still need to work with real computer, but using VirtualBox may save a lot of developer time and resources.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is workable, There are actually some sites supply pre-configed applications:

[BitNami](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/redmine)

[turnkeylinux](http://turnkeylinux)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully my necro-posting adds some value...

Is this is a server type product that runs on Linux (either client-server model; or with a WebUI)? Assuming that it is, I think distributing via a vm image is a good way to go.

But why lock yourself down to one image type? Especially one that is not really ideal for Production usage. Why not support most of the big virtualization providers (and bare metal)!?

So long as you can script the install (and there's almost always a way that you can) and it will work on Debian, then you can build yourself a software appliance in a load of different build types (inc. OVA, VMDK, hybrid ISO etc) using TurnKey Linux's [TKLDev](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/docs/tkldev) build engine. The major VM platform that it doesn't (yet) support is Hyper-V but the ISO installs.